# Pandas: split the index of a dafaframe out of a nested dictionary and add a number to the new split column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, split

Let's say I have this small nested dictionary:

```
dict = {'f1': {'A 1': 'A1', 'B 1': 'B1'}, 'f2': {'A 1': 'A2', 'B 1': 'B2'}, "f3": {'A 1': 'A3', 'B 1': 'B3'}}
```

with:
`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)`

it outputs:

```
     f1  f2  f3
A 1  A1  A2  A3
B 2  B1  B2  B3
```

I would like to split the index using the " " separator and add a X number to the second entry of the index.
The desired output, with x=1 should be:

```
L N  f1  f2  f3
A 2  A1  A2  A3
B 3  B1  B2  B3
```

I have tried:

```
df.index = df.index.str.split(" ")
```

and the output is:

```
        f1  f2  f3
[A, 1]  A1  A2  A3
[B, 2]  B1  B2  B3
```

From here I don't know what to do to increase the number in the index.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.index = df.index.str.split(' ')
df.index = df.index.str[0] + ' ' + (df.index.str[1].astype(int) + 1).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     f1  f2  f3
A 2  A1  A2  A3
B 3  B1  B2  B3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a programmatic way:

```
X = zip(*((a, int(b)+1) for a,b in df.index.map(str.split)))
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(X, names=['L', 'N'])
```

output:

```
     f1  f2  f3
L N            
A 2  A1  A2  A3
B 3  B1  B2  B3
```